# How to add a new timestamps column in adonisjs

Tags: migration, adonis.js

I'm trying to add a new timestamp column in a migration but I can't.

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class UsersNewColoumnSchema extends Schema {
    up() {
        this.table('users', (table) => {
            table.timestamps('token_time')
        })
    }
}

module.exports = UsersNewColoumnSchema
```

The error message is:

```
" sqlMessage: 'Duplicate column name \'updated_at\'', "
```

I don't understand because my new column name isn't `updated_at`.

Answer (score 0):

my question was answered
[here](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/how-to-add-a-new-timestamps-column-in-adonisjs/6225)!